# How to add missing read-more link to drupal 7 teaser

Tags: drupal-7, teaser

When customizing a drupal 7 theme about a year ago I removed the code that displays the read-more link at the end of teasers.

I need to add this code back to show the read-more links now, but I have totally forgotten where to put this code in.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a file in your template with suffix `*-teaser.tpl.php` and in proper location add  like [this example](https://github.com/misd-service-development/drupal-feature-teasers/blob/master/templates/node----teaser.tpl.php) or another [example of marinellie theme](https://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites%21all%21themes%21marinelli%21templates%21node--teaser.tpl.php/7.54)

```
    <span class="teaser-readmore"><?php print l(t('read more'), 'node/' . $nid, array('attributes' => array('class' => t('node-readmore-link')))); ?></span>
```

**Another** solution is look for how was it implemented it your main theme ( looking for `*--teaser.tpl.php`  and just copy/paste *read_more* section)

Comment: Thank you, I remember deleting similar code from some template file in my drupal 7 theme. However, I just installed https://www.drupal.org/project/read_more module and then run the cron to make it effective. This module is working for me nicely as it allows to modify the "read me" text to whatever language, my site is in Urdu language (right to left like Arabic),